# Docker Windows 10 is not able to share driver

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am using Docker 18.03.0-ce-win59 (16762) on my windows machine. I am using

```
docker run --rm -v d:/data:/data ubuntu ls /data
```

command to mount the host machine folder to the container. While running it asks for the sharing the driver. I selected the docker settings -> Shared Drivers -> Selected D drive and clicked Apply button. Then the window becomes unresponsive. 
[image]